# Changing type of 32-bit variable to 64-bit variable?

Tags: c

My application runs on a pSOS operating system. The code is compiled with Diab C compiler.

The application defines a number of counters which have been declared as

```
unsigned int call_count;
```

As there are chances of some of these overflowing in a small time frame, I have decided to declare the counters as

```
unsigned long long int call_count;
```

This I believe would not overflow at least during my lifetime.

My question is this conversion harmless? Are there any overhead that I need to concerned with. When the application is under stress the call_count would be incremented incessantly. Can performance take a hit ? A SNMP manager would be querying these counters every 15 seconds as well.

Comment: If you just use ordinary long, you could do 1000 per second for the next several billion years without overflowing.

Comment: If he uses ordinary long, he would do 1000 per second for 47 days without overflowing. That's what Windows 98 did.

Comment: @Paul: The SNMP Manager uses counter64 . Hence I have to declare it as 'long long'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your code assuming that incrementing a 32-bit variable is an atomic operation? Incrementing a 64-bit variable on a 32-bit CPU probably won't be atomic unless you go out of your way to make it so.

Example:

1. `call_count` equals `0x00000005FFFFFFFF` when a call comes in.
2. The lower half of `call_count` is incremented: `call_count` gets set to `0x000000500000000` and the CPU's carry bit gets set to 1.
3. The upper half of `call_count` is incremented by the carry bit: `call_count` gets set to `0x0000000600000000`.

If another thread or an interrupt handler reads the value of `call_count` between steps 2 and 3, it will get the wrong result (`0x000000500000000` instead of `0x000000600000000`). The solution is to synchronize access to `call_count`. A few possibilities:

- Disable interrupts (if appropriate)
- Serialize access using a lock
- Read and write using atomic/interlocked functions (example: `InterlockedIncrement()` on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a performance issue, at least if you use a 64 bit processor, since the variable is almost always in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Within broad limits, the change is harmless.  You will need to be sure that any code accessing the value is prepared to handle a 64-bit quantity, and any code that formats its value will need to be changed, but otherwise, it should be safe enough -- in the absence of any information about other code that would be broken by the change.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine.

I assume (from the pSOS) that you're coding to a Moto 68000, which is a 32-bit processor; working with 64-bit numbers is slightly slower there because it needs a few more instructions (eg, add, check carry, branch or add to high word) but I doubt you're worried much about a four cycle cost. If you are on a 64-bit processor, then 64-bit ops are exactly as fast as 32-bit ones.

Doing this will increase your memory storage overhead of course, but again that's only a concern if you've a great many structures containing these counters.